# Getting property from array and replace

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this array:

```
object(stdClass)#458 (2) {
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#456 (3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(3) "Test Product 1"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1)
    ["price"]=>
    int(1221)
  }
  ["shipping"]=>
  object(stdClass)#457 (3) {
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1)
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "Free Delivery"
    ["price"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

I'm displaying this on the page like this.

```
@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->order_details) as $itemId => 
     <?php $total += ($item->price * $item->quantity); ?>
     <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $item->title }}</h4>
      {{ $item->quantity }}
      ${{ $item->price * $item->quantity }} / €{{ $order['total_eur'] }}
@endforeach
```

So far everything works perfect except the addition value which I call from database `$order['total_eur']`. This value is saved when order is placed so I then show total in USD and total in EUR.

The problem here is that `${{ $item->price * $item->quantity }}` contain also shipping and when shipping is Free e.g. $ 0 is shown on page

```
Test Product 1   $122 /  €113      
Free Delivery    $0 / €113
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace somehow when the delivery is free e.g. `["shipping"]=>["price"] = 0` to show `0` instead. to be like this:

```
Test Product 1   $122 /  €113      
Free Delivery    $0 / €0
```

I can access it like this

```
<?php $shipping = $order->getOrderData($order->order_details)->shipping->price; ?>
```

But I can't figured it out how can I change it in the `foreach` loop.

I hope I explained this clear and understandable. Can anyone suggest something that may work?

Update: I've tried this simple if inside foreach but still showing both eur price on both

```
${{ $item->price * $item->quantity }} 
  @if( ! $order->getOrderData($order->order_details)->shipping) 
      {{ $order->getOrderData($order->order_details)->shipping->price }} 
  @else 
      €{{ $order['total_eur'] }} 
  @endif
```

Comment: Its quite confusing? A simple if would do inside foreach loop?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar, I've updated my question with the if condition I tried but still same

Comment: No, I mean check if price is zero, like @if($item->price) then it is free delivery, else normal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->order_details) as $itemId => $item)
     <?php $total += ($item->price * $item->quantity); ?>
     <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $item->title }}</h4>
      {{ $item->quantity }}
      @if ($itemId == "shipping" && $item->price == 0) 
        $0 / €0
      @else
        ${{ $item->price * $item->quantity }} / €{{ $order['total_eur'] }}
      @endif
@endforeach
```

Here we are checking the array whether it is shipping item and price is set to zero. If so we are displaying zero €, else we are displaying the actual cost.

Comment: Yes, this is work for the question I've asked. I found out that there is something else that Is missing here. Thanks

Comment: But the delivery can be different from zero.. paid one. This mean with above code will show total_eur again